# Bash Copy folder content, not folder

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I would like to copy the contents of a folder to another one, without copying the actual folder itself. For example, in /dirA/dirB/ I have a.txt, b.txt and c.txt. I would like to do:

```
cp -r /dirA/dirB/ /some/folder/
```

In a way that a.txt, b.txt and c.txt are in /some/folder, not in /some/folder/dirB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cp /dirA/dirB/*.txt /some/folder
```

will do that, avoiding the `-r` option.

Comment: If there are folders to copy under dirB, -r option would be necessary. Just for the record.

Comment: @purplehuman: it depends, in part, on where the (hypothetical) files under `/dirA/dirB/anotherDir` are supposed to go.  If they're also meant to end up in `/some/folder`, then `-r` is not the way to go (they'll end up in `/some/folder/anotherDir`).  If they are meant to go in the sub-directory, you can modify what I supplied (`cp -r /dirA/dirB/*.txt /dirA/dirB/anotherDir/ /some/folder`) to do the job. Also GNU [`cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) has the useful `-t /some/folder` option that could be used with `find` to move the files to the target.

Comment: Great expalanation. Thanks.